Description of the basis of the normal and tangent spaces
I’m a second year physics student. I’m currently following analytical mechanics lectures. The professor is following the book “Analytical mechanics”, by Fasano and Marmi and they both have a very rigorous approach for a second year class. The first lectures had the purpose to introduce some concepts of differential geometry (I have little to no background of the prerequisites, topology and groups, as my university didn't arrange preparatory courses, however any book suggestion is well accepted!).
Before the introduction of the concept of submanifold we have deloped some kind of frameowork in the more tangible $\mathbb{R}^3$ space. If I want to describe a surface of some kind I can think of it in three ways:

As the $0$ level set of a function $F : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$ S = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 | F(\mathbf{x}) = 0 \} $$

As the graph of a real valued function $f : W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of two variables, $\mathrm{Gr}f$, such that

$$ S = \mathrm{Gr}f = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R} | (x_1, x_2, f(x_1, x_2))\} $$
Using  the implicit function theorem (in this case it is required that $\mathbf{x}$ is non singular) and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_3}(\mathbf{x}) \neq 0$ for every $\mathbf{x}$

As the image of a parameterization  vector function $\mathbf{x} : \mathrm{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathrm{R}^3$

Now in the first case, the condition for a point $\mathbf{x}_0$ to be non singular is that:
$$\nabla F (P) \neq \mathbf{0}$$
and in the third case is
$$ \mathrm{rg} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial v} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
= \mathrm{rg} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix} = 2 $$
Now it is possible to prove that for every non singular point $P$ of $S$ a base for the tangent space, $T_P S$ is given by the two linearly independent vectors $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial v}$. Moreover:
$$\nabla F (P) = (T_P S)^\perp$$
Now, since $\mathbb{R} = T_P S \oplus (T_P S)^\perp = T_P S \oplus \nabla F (P)$, thus $\{ \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial v}, \nabla F \}_P$ is a base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for every $P$ which is non singular.
This are the doubts I have matured:

It seems that speeking of the base of the normal space, $\{\nabla F (P)\}$ implies using the first description for the set $S$ ($S$ as the level set of a function $F$), while speeking of the tangent space base $\{\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial v} \}$  implies using the third description for the set $S$ ($S$ as the set of all point in the image of the parameterization function $\mathbf{x}$). Why is it possible to mix up the two representation? Is the tangent space parameterization-dependent while the normal base it is independent from the parameterization?

Now, looking at $\mathbb{R}^2, instead, let the set $S$ have one degree of freedom (therefore it is described by a curve $\mathbf{\varphi}$), how can be interpreted the directional derivative $\frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf{v}}$ along a level set? Must $\mathbf{v}$ be a member of $T_P S$, $S$ being represented by the level set? If so, $\mathbf{v}$ would be a linear combination of the basis vectors of $T_P S$: $\mathbf{v} = \lambda \frac{\partial \mathbf{\varphi}}{\partial t}$, while $\nabla F$ refers to the level set representation. If the function $F$ is differentiable, it holds that:


$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \mathbf{v}} = \left< \nabla F, \mathbf{v} \right> $$
How can I interpret the directional derivative as the result of the scalar product between vectors associated with two different representations of the same $S$?
Thank you very much in advance for your time!

How can $S$ have one degree of freedom if it is a $2$-dimensional surface in $\Bbb R^3$?

Sorry, I omitted to say to consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the final part of the question, when I talk about the $\mathbf{\varphi}$ function that parameterize $S$
